# IE Automation - VBA Error - Runtime Error 70: Permission Denied

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, runtime-error, export-to-excel

Friends, I'm very new to VBA and here I'm trying to scrape data from an internal website. The process goes like this: There are few serial numbers entered in the column A3 to End. The macro is supposed to navigate to the URL --> pick the serial number from excel --> Enter in the Search Field and Click Search. Once the result is populated on the page, it scrapes specific values and populates in the excel sheet.

The page opens up well, data is picked from excel and when the macro is reading the table cells it gives ***Runtime 70 Error***. Below is my code for reference. Any help to fix is much appreciated.

```
Sub Type1_Data()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim RowNumber, ColumnNumber As Long
    RowNumber = 3
    ColumnNumber = 0

    Dim i As Long
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Filt As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim mtbl As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim strempid As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    Dim strempid1 As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    Dim strempid2 As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    Dim strempid3 As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    Dim strempid4 As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    Dim strempid5 As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    Dim strempid6 As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate ("URL")

    Do While ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
xy:
    If HTMLDoc.Title <> "Marketplace | Find a professional" Then
        ie.Visible = True
    
        GoTo xy
    End If
    ie.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Dim Ed As Integer
    Ed = 3
    While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProM Search").Cells(Ed, 1).Value <> 0
        Ed = Ed + 1
    Wend
    Ed = Ed - 1
    For i = 3 To Ed
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Set UID = HTMLDoc.getElementById("navSelect")
        Set Filt = HTMLDoc.getElementById("searchText")
        Set mtbl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("Table")(23)
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        HTMLDoc.getElementById("NLQTextArea").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProM Search").Cells(i, 1).Value
        HTMLDoc.getElementById("submitAction").Click

        Set strempid = mtbl.getElementsByClassName("dojoxGridCell")(1)
        Set strempid1 = mtbl.getElementsByClassName("dojoxGridCell")(2)
        Set strempid2 = mtbl.getElementsByClassName("dojoxGridCell")(3)
        Set strempid3 = mtbl.getElementsByClassName("dojoxGridCell")(7)
        Set strempid4 = mtbl.getElementsByClassName("dojoxGridCell")(9)
        Set strempid5 = mtbl.getElementsByClassName("dojoxGridCell")(11)
        Set strempid6 = mtbl.getElementsByClassName("dojoxGridCell")(12)

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = strempid.innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = strempid1.innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = strempid2.innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = strempid3.innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = strempid4.innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = strempid5.innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = strempid6.innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -7).Activate
        DoEvents
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Fetching Completed Successfully", vbExclamation, "ProM - Open Seat Search T2"
            GoTo qt
        End If
    Next

qt:
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLDoc.getElementById("submitAction").Click` may cause a page refresh making any referenced elements become stale. Try working always of `ie.document` rather than setting into a variable when performing actions likely/known to cause page refresh/update. This is a common cause of a permission denied error.

Your `If End If` should probably be a loop with time out. You only need the one `ie.visible = True`. You rarely gain from setting Visible to false in my opinion. If you intend to hide it from a user you should do so from the start unless it interferes with functionality.

No point for `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` as it is never switched off within this sub. If this sub is called then you only need it once outside the loop. Your repeated `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate` can just use a loop with `Select Case` and set the value direct without activate. Repeating the line `Do While ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop` serves no purpose.

You could use `Find` method of range to determine the row in column 1 where 0 occurs rather than walking down the column. And tests to determine it is found and >=3.

Comment: Hello, You are right! HTMLDoc.getElementById("submitAction").Click is causing the issue here. I have changed it to ie.doc.getElementById("submitAction").Click and still no luck. Could you please advice further here?

Comment: You need to do this for what comes after the click

Answer (score 0):

This error means an attempt was made to write to a write-protected disk or to access a locked file. You could check if special permission is needed to access the worksheet. For detailed causes and solutions, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/permission-denied-error-70).

Besides, you can also refer to my working sample about reading the cell value in VBA:

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "https://www.bing.com"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    Set doc = ieA.Document
    Dim tempStr As String
    tempStr = "sb_form_q"
    doc.getElementById(tempStr).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("E2").Value
End Sub
```